# Run of plugin ATL

Tags: java

I am using ATl plugin to lunch atl using java class.

but when  I want to  run   this plugin , I  have a problem as :
Arguments not valid : {IN_model_path, OUT_model_path}.

Does anyone know how can i  resolve this problem to generate de outmodel.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: PlugIn for what? Could you show us some code?

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   if (args.length < 2) {    
    GramWSDL2WSDL runner = new GramWSDL2WSDL();
    runner.loadModels("C:/Users/samsung/Desktop/copie de workspace/ATLplugin/eclipsehelio avec atl - Copie/workspace/GramWSDL2WSDL/model");
    runner.doGramWSDL2WSDL(new NullProgressMonitor());
    runner.saveModels("C:/Users/samsung/Desktop/copie de workspace/ATLplugin/eclipsehelio avec atl - Copie/workspace/GramWSDL2WSDL/model");  
   }
   else 
   System.out.println("Arguments not valid : {IN_model_path, OUT_model_path}.");

  }
  `

Comment: the plugin is   ATL plugin.